# Azure data factory pass activity output to a dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using a SQL Server query which would return the last 3 months since a customer last purchased a product. For instance, There's a customer 100 that last made a purchase in August 2022. The SQL query will return June, July, August. Which would be in the format 062022, 072022, 082022. Now I need to be able to pass these values to the Copy data activity REST api dataset Relative URL (/salemonyr/062022) in the ForEach activity.

[image]

So during the first iteration the Relative URL should be set to `/salemonyr/062022` the second would be `/salemonyr/072022` and third `/salemonyr/082022`.

**Error:** `The expression 'length(activity('MonYear').output.value)' cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist, available properties are 'resultSetCount, recordsAffected, resultSets, outputParameters, outputLogs, outputLogsLocation, outputTruncated, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, executionDuration, durationInQueue, billingReference`

***Script activity json:***

```
{
    "resultSetCount": 1,
    "recordsAffected": 0,
    "resultSets": [
        {
            "rowCount": 3,
            "rows": [
                {
                    "MonYear": 062022
                },
                {
                    "MonYear": 072022
                },
                {
                    "MonYear": 082022
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputParameters": {},
    "outputLogs": "",
    "outputLogsLocation": "",
    "outputTruncated": false,
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 3
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How would I accomplish this to read the values dynamically from the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@split(item().colname,',')[0]` , `split(item().colname,',')[1]` and `split(item().colname,',')[2]` in the relative URL path.

Check the below video for details:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **REST** Dataset parameter and use it in the **Relative URL**.

[image]

Relative URL:

[image]

Give lookup output to ForEach. use your query in lookup.

[image]

Give this to ForEach and inside ForEach, in copy sink(REST DATASET) use the below expression for the dataset parameter.

```
/salemonyr/@{item().sample_date}
```

[image]

In source, you can give your source.

By this, you can copy the data to the respective Relative URL.